# How trigger router-link click before blur on vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want search in an input and show the results. When show the div of results after typing on input, some routes appears which I want to click on them an go to the another page.
Beside if I click outside the input search close the div of results. I change the `visible` to false on it's `blur`.
But `blur` trigger before `router-link` click. So when I click on router-link can't go to the new page.
How can I force `blur` trigger after `click`? or trigger not on the div of results?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show() {
      this.visible = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input @keyup="show()" @blur="visible = false"/>
    <div v-if="visible">
      <router-link
        to="{name: 'sample', params: {sample: 'sample'}}"
      >
       Go to another page
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the link on input blur you may hide the link in the click listener of the router link like I did in the code below. But However why do you need to hide the link ? Change in route will make it removed.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
                visible: false
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addListener() {
            document.querySelector('#app').addEventListener("click", hideLink );
            this.visible = true;
        }
    }
})


function hideLink(params) {
    document.querySelector('#app').removeEventListener("click", hideLink );
    this.visible = false;
}
```

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
        <div>
            <input @focus="addListener" />
            <div v-if="visible">
                <router-link
                    to="{name: 'sample', params: {sample: 'sample'}}"
                    @click.prevent.native="visible = false"
                >
                    Go to another page
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In this way when click on other part of page can't hide the result div, which I need

Comment: Okay you can then add a event listener to the #app and when a click is detected you can hide the link and remove the listener

Comment: I've upadted the code. you can try this way

Comment: It seems it happens again the click of listener apply sooner than going to a new page. the url changed but stay in the page not goes to the new one